# TypeScript creating nested build folder on rebuild

Tags: typescript, build, tsconfig

When I try to rebuild the project, TS somehow thinks that the files inside build folder also have  **to be compiled**.
It does not respect the `rootDir` property in the `tsconfig.json` file

Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "commonjs",

    "allowJs": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "strict": true,

    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,

    "baseUrl": "./app",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./app",

    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

And here is the directory structure

```
server
├── app
│   ├── models
│   └── routes
│       └── index.ts
├── server.ts
├── build
├── Dockerfile
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

Here is the first build

```
build
├── routes
│   ├── index.d.ts
│   ├── index.d.ts.map
│   └── index.js
├── server.d.ts
├── server.d.ts.map
└── server.js
```

And here is the second build

```
build
├── app
│   ├── routes
│   │   ├── index.d.ts
│   │   ├── index.d.ts.map
│   │   └── index.js
│   ├── server.d.ts
│   ├── server.d.ts.map
│   └── server.js
├── build
│   ├── routes
│   │   ├── index.d.ts
│   │   ├── index.d.ts.map
│   │   └── index.js
│   ├── server.d.ts
│   ├── server.d.ts.map
│   └── server.js
├── routes
│   ├── index.d.ts
│   ├── index.d.ts.map
│   └── index.js
├── server.d.ts
├── server.d.ts.map
└── server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I did not mention the `include` property!

Adding a `"include": ["./app/**/*"]` after the `compilerOptions` resolves the issue.